# matplotlib.PatchCollection always getting drawn last

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, draw, patch

I have a `matplotlib.PatchCollection` that I want to add to a plot. But I also have Text and other Patches I am adding straight onto the plot. So it looks like this:

```
node.shape = RegularPolygon((node.posX, node.posY),
                            6,
                radius = node.radius,
                                    edgecolor = 'none',
                                    facecolor = node.fillColor,
                                    zorder = node.zorder)


self.patches.append(node.shape)
self.p = PatchCollection(self.patches, edgecolor = 'none', match_original=True )       
self.plotAxes.add_collection(self.p) 

#Two previously instantiated patches (they are visible)
self.plotAxes.add_artist(selectionRect)
self.plotAxes.add_artist(brushShape)

self.plotCanvas.draw()
```

I want my Patches in the collection to be drawn first and then the `selctionRect` and `brushShape` to be drawn afterwards because they can overlap the Patches in the collection. If they do, they should be visible. However, my plot always shows the Patches in the collection as if they've been drawn last. How can I get around this? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** One thing that appears to work is to keep 2 PatchCollections. However, when I do this, it seems that I can never set the visibilities to false. Does the `PatchCollection` set the reset the values or something?

Comment: I believe you can alter the z value to change what's plotted on top.  Higher z values are placed on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adam said in the comments you want to set `zorder`, which sets what order things layer when they are drawn on top of each other, things with higher `zorder` will overlap things with lower `zorder`.

Everything has a default `zorder`, but you can over-ride that value by adding the `zorder` kwarg to the function call.  It is an `Artist` kwarg, so basically ever plotting function should respect it (and if you find one that does not submit a bug report to the github site)

ex

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(range(5), zorder=2, lw=10)
ax.plot(range(5)[::-1], zorder=1, lw=10)
```

vs

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(range(5), zorder=1, lw=10)
ax.plot(range(5)[::-1], zorder=2, lw=10)
```

[zorder demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html)

Comment: I see this works when I am just using add_artist(Patch), but even when I adjust the zorder for my collection I still get the same problem. Do PatchCollections themselves have a zorder or do all of the patches use their individual values?

Comment: @Sterling Patch collections are artist in and of them selves, you can set the zorder of the whole collection.  I am not sure how overlaps within a collection are sorted out though.